# unix find command ending with '+' character

Tags: unix, command-line, find

While perusing some AWS docs I noticed the following command:

```
find /var/www -type d -exec sudo chmod 2775 {} +
```

I'm familiar with the \; ending to exec in a find string but have never seen the '+'. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Here's the original page: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html

Thanks!

Comment: you could think of it as placing all the results from `find` as arguments to `chmod` in one go.  so its faster than using `;`

Comment: see `man find` for more

Answer (score 3):

If you use a plus (`+`) instead of the escaped semicolon, the arguments will be grouped together before being passed to the command. For example:

```
$ find . -type f -exec echo {} +
. ./bar.txt ./foo.txt
```

In this case, only one child process (`echo . ./bar.txt ./foo.txt`)is created which is much more efficient, because it avoids a fork/exec for each single argument.

Using the escaped semi-colon, you will get a child process created for each argument.

```
$ find . -type f -exec echo {} \;
. 
./bar.txt
./foo.txt
```

Comment: Very nice! Thank you - that also explains why find commands that return lots of args don't work sometimes with the '+' - e.g. `find . -name "*" -exec chmod 700 {} +` (chmod complains of too long a command line)